# Are $\mathfrak{Re}\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{Im}\varphi$ characteristic functions?

Tags: probability

Let $\varphi$ be the characteristic function of a random variable X. Are $\mathfrak{Re}\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{Im}\varphi$ characteristic functions?

I'm very stuck on this question. I'm not sure what would be required to prove that something is a characteristic function. It seems like these function does not violate any of the basic properties of characteristic functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties. So I cannot say that these are *not* characteristic functions. However, I do not know what is required to show that these definitely *are* characteristic functions.

So far my only thoughts have been to say $\varphi(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})=f(t)+ig(t)$ for some functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and then the question is whether $f$ and $g$ are characteristic functions. I thought this would be a simple question, but I am quite stuck, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $f(t)=\frac 1 2 \left(\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})+\mathbb{E}(e^{-itX})\right)$ so $f$ can be obtained as the characteristic function of the mixture of $X$ and $-X$. One way to think about it, if $X$ has density $p(x)$ then $f$ is the characteristic function of the random variable with density $\frac 1 2 (p(x)+p(-x))$.

Comment: What Stefan Lafon said handles the real part case. Do you have an idea about the imaginary part case? (If you don't, here's my hint: in general what's $\varphi(0)$?)

Comment: $g(t)=\frac12\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})-\mathbb{E}(e^{-itX})\right)$. However, I'm still unsure how we now know that $f,g$ are characteristic functions?

Comment: So following the same logic, $g(t)$ is the characteristic function of the variable with density $\frac12(p(x)-p(-x))$, but this is not a valid random variable, since integrating over the reals returns 0, not 1? So am I right in saying that $\mathfrak{Im}\varphi$ is not a characteristic function?

Comment: The imaginary part cannot be the ch. function of a probability distribution.  All ch. functions have $\phi(0)=1$, so the imaginary part $=0$ at $t=0$ and cannot be a ch. function.

Comment: So first with the imaginary part you have to divide by $2i$. And it is true that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx} \frac{p(x)-p(-x)}{2i} dx$ gives you $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi(t))$. But $\frac{p(x)-p(-x)}{2i}$ is not a probability density; it's either imaginary or zero everywhere, and it integrates to zero. This problem carries over to the case without densities, but actually completing the proof is easier if you notice $\varphi(0)=1$ for any characteristic function $\varphi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ have density $p(x)$. Then $f(t)=\frac12\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})+\mathbb{E}(e^{-itX})\right)$. So $f(t)$ is the characteristic function of the variable with density $\frac12(p(x)+p(-x))$.

On the other hand, since $\varphi(t)$ is a characteristic function, we have $\varphi(0)=1$. So then we have $g(0)=\mathfrak{Im}(\varphi(0))=\mathfrak{Im}(0)=0$, so $g(t)$ is not a characteristic function.

Comment: Please add a solution to the case of the real part.